# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa000000617461644'

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am developing simple app that gets json data and stores into different variables
 here is my code that gets json data

```
if ([method isEqualToString:@"getmobiledata"]){

       defaultDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
         [defaultDict addEntriesFromDictionary:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil]];
         mobile = [defaultDict objectForKey:@"data"];

    }
```

here  is my son data:

```
{
    data =     (
                {
            id = 1;
            package = 819MB;
            rate = "$1";
            type = Somnet;
        },
                {
            id = 2;
            package = "1,638MB";
            rate = "$2";
            type = Somnet;
        },

    );
}
```

here is paring json into nstring  :

```
for(NSDictionary *getData in mobile){
         NSString *idno  = [getData objectForKey : @"id"];
         NSString *package = [getData objectForKey :@"package"];
         NSString *rate = [getData objectForKey :@"rate"];
         NSString *type = [getData objectForKey :@"type"];

    }
```

please help me how to solve this

Comment: Invalid json format

Comment: please help me how to solve

Comment: The error is saying that at some point an object is a `NSString` and not a `NSDictionary` as you may think. That's strange, the part you gave shouldn't do that, if what you printed is `defaultDict`. Debug, find the line, and give us the variables in that case.

Answer (score -1):

The data model will collide with the same name as the system property ID, and it will collide and crash.
You can use a new ID like this:

`- (void)setValue:(id)value forUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key  {
    if([key isEqualToString:@"id"])
        self.NewId = value;
}`